# Операционная система для Android и Adobe Flex- разработчика

Tags: windows, android, ос, linux

Здравствуйте!

Озадачился вопросом выбора ОС для ноутбука, на котором работаю. Разрабатываю приложения для ОС Android и Flash приложения на Adobe Flash Builder.

Характеристики ноутбука: 
Модель: Lenovo Y570 
CPU: Core i3-230M (2.1 GHz) 
RAM: 6 GB DDRIII 1333 
HDD: 500 GB  
SSD: 60 GB 
VIdeo: #1: Intel HD 3000; #2 nVidia GEFORCE GT 555M.

Сейчас установлен Windows 8 х64 Профессиональная

Думаю установить систему на SSD. Но винда очень много места свободного на этом ссд в данный момент жрет...

В общем, прошу Вас посоветовать какую систему, и на какой накопитель установить...

Если вдруг кто-то еще до сюда дочитает, может кто-то натыкался в и-нете на инструкцию по установке ССД в качестве кеша для жесткого диска? Не могу найти... в моделях Y570, которые идут с ССД сразу, именно таким образом и объединены ССД и жесткий диск.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После получения всех 0 ответов тут, а так же на ответ.мейл.ру пошел экспериментировать.

Поставил Ubuntu 12.10 x64

Установил Eclipse(ADT) + неофициальный плагин Flash Builder + плагин Aptana. 
После некоторого времени исполнения этнических танцев народов севера, удалось так же установить дебаговую версию флеш плеера для мозиллы.

Так же удалось некоторыми усилиями заставить разотать Optimus (переключение между видеокартами), и даже установить и запустить при помощи великого Wine Flat Out 2 без тормозов и каких-либо лагов.

Так что, товарищи, выбрасываем винду))